# Function with IF and ELIF using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

What is a better way (if there is one) to define a function that checks whether a pandas column is within a given range of integers?

I have a column in a Pandas dataframe which I wanted to check whether the values are between a set range. I chose to do so by creating a function which accepts the dataframe as an argument and tests whether the column is within the range using IF and ELIF. 
This may be ok where the range is small, however if the range is large, the resulting IF, ELIF function can be daunting to maintain. Is there a better way to achieve this?

My code that works-

```
def fn(dframe):
    if dframe['A'] < 125:
        return 935 + 0.2 * dframe['A']

    elif (dframe['A'] >= 955) and (dframe['A'] <= 974):
        return 921.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 955)

    elif (dframe['A'] >= 975) and (dframe['A'] <= 1023):
        return 925.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['BCCH'] - 975)

    elif (dframe['A'] >= 511) and (dframe['A'] <= 885):
        return 1805.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 512)
```

This code works as expected however if the range is large, the resultant function is difficult to manage.

EDIT:

Thanks @ycx, @Jorge and all- I like the readability of your code. However was wondering like @ycx's approach If I have the Min and Max values of the 'condlist' in a csv file - such as

[condlist_from_CSV_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IulQY.png)

then I can read that in to a dataframe. Now, I would like to check if every row of a column 'A' from another dataframe is between these limits and if true, then return the corresponding 'Choice', else return 'None' does that make sense?
Desired Output -

[output dataframe with check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHXGp.png)

and so on..

Comment: is dframe['BCCH']  in the second ELIF a typo?

Comment: What's supposed to happen to values that don't fall into any of the ranges? (For example, 130.)

Comment: Your code should fail because `if some_series < 125` is undefined.. Try it yourself.. `if pd.Series([1, 2, 3]) < 125: print('hello')` gives (correctly) `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Please supply a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Jorge - sorry, yes meant dframe['A'] and not dframe['BCCH']

Comment: NPE - if none of teh conditions are true then return 'None'

Comment: My posted answer was incorrect so I deleted it. @ycx's answer should get the work done for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need np.where

```
import numpy as np
np.where(dframe['A'] < 125, 935 + 0.2 * dframe['A'],
       np.where(dframe['A'] >= 511) & (dframe['A'] <= 885), 1805.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 512,
       np.where(dframe['A'] <= 974, 921.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 955),
       np.where(dframe['A'] <= 1023, 925.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 975),
    'Value for any other value'))))
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge. What if there were more than just the 4 ranges that I had to test each value?

Comment: @Ananth iif you need more ranges you add more np.where conditions. Just meke sure they are in order and that all your values in the colum are covered.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge. If I have a larger range in a csv file, then can I read that file in and use np.where to check whether my values are within that range?

Comment: @Ananth, Yes, all you need is to read you csv file with pd.read_csv and it will be a dataframe where you can apply np.where.

Comment: You can try: bins = [0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100] and then df.loc[:,'A'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], bins), but it will not take your condition for each bin and you end up reruning something like np.where

Comment: Thanks Jorge,
Following your advice, I have a file with the following columns and values -

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `np.select` to manage your conditions and options. This allows you to maintain your conditions and options easily and makes use of the `numpy` library functions which may help speed up your code

```
def fn(dframe):
    import numpy as np
    condlist = [
            dframe['A'] < 125, 
            (dframe['A'] >= 955) and (dframe['A'] <= 974),
            (dframe['A'] >= 975) and (dframe['A'] <= 1023),
            (dframe['A'] >= 511) and (dframe['A'] <= 885),
            ]
    choicelist = [
            935 + 0.2 * dframe['A'],
            921.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 955),
            925.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['BCCH'] - 975),
            1805.2 + 0.2 * (dframe['A'] - 512),
            ]
    output = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks @ycx   - 1) How can I extend this for more than 4 ranges?
2) can np.select read values from a list and apply the conditions accordingly?

Comment: @Ananth  Not sure what you mean. np.select is already taking in a condition list and a choice list in this very example. I think that answers your question of 1 and 2 since you simply have to add to the 2 lists? Could you elaborate further otherwise?

Comment: Thanks @ycx- I like the readability of your code. However was wondering, If I have the Min and Max values of the 'condlist' in a csv file - such as 
Cond_Min Cond_Max Choice
783.5 798.5 -4.02
798.5 813.5 -3.16, then obviously I can read that in to a dataframe. Now, I would like to check if every row of a column 'A' from another dataframe is between these limits and if true, then return the corresponding 'Choice', else return 'None' does that make sense?
Desired Output -
'A' 'Check'
789 -4.02
780 -3.16, and so on...

Comment: @Ananth `np.select` has a `default` argument in which you can pass in `None`. This would mean that if none of the conditions in condlist are fulfilled, it will output `None` since it is the default. So like `output = np.select(condlist, choicelist, None)` `np.select` will return a `numpy.array` object, which is `list`-like and you can assign directly to a column for another dataframe